# Matching Specific Filenames

Tags: regex

I can't figure this exercise at RegexOne.come: http://regexone.com/example/4?

This was my solution: `(^.*\.(jpg|png|gif)$)`

The capture text shows up green, but my result is all green checks except for the 3 that I need.

I tried this too: `(^.*(\.jpg|\.png|\.gif)$)﻿`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
(^.*)\.(jpg|png|gif)$
```

Comment: Thank you Anton. I just needed to close the `^.*)` instead of at the end.